# Sample size when using GPS-trackers to analyze movement of reindeers

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size, computational-statistics, descriptive-statistics

If one were to try and analyze the movement of ~2 500 reindeers before and after a (man-made) change in landscape have occured. Specifically how spread out the herd is, both as a whole and if there are more or less individuals and small groups running away from the big herd.

Do anyone have any ideas on how many animals one needs to mark with a GPS to get any kind of credible results, ie. sample size?

I've tried to find previous work in the area, but none have touched the subject of sample size. So any and all help is highly appreciated.

edit: "deer" to "reindeer"

Comment: Could you explain what it means to "mark" an animal with a GPS?  Exactly how are you proposing to collect animal locations?

Comment: It is a collar with GPS and geolocation is then recorded of each "marked" animal. This data can then be used to analyze the spread of the herd. Now we have yet to define spread, but that is a question for later.